# Ajax request repeat the same value from PHP

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, loops

I really searched for information more than a week, but I did not find solution.

I work with ajax in wordpress with wp_ajax,
my target is get images from post type attachment with ajax 
I have already made this step, but when I click in the button to call ajax, this show all images attachment, I want to show images sequentially.

I research info about loop relation to offset and paged, but all info is about pagination post.

This my code in the plugin.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_post_myaction_add_myaction', 'post_myaction_add_myaction' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_post_myaction_add_myaction', 'post_myaction_add_myaction' );

function post_myaction_add_myaction($size = "full") {

    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    $limit = $_POST['limit'];
    $offset = $_POST['offset'];

            // get images using the get_posts() function
        $images = get_posts(array(
            'numberposts'    => -1, // get all images
            'post_mime_type' => 'image', // so we can get images
            'numberposts' => $limit,
            'post_parent'    => $post_id, // get images attached to the current post
            'offset' => $offset,
            'post_type'      => 'attachment',
            'order'          => 'ASC',
            'orderby'        => 'menu_order' // pull them out in the order you set them as
        ));

        // loop through images and display them
        foreach($images as $image) {
            echo wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID, $size); // returns an image HTML tag if there is one
        }

      die();   

    }
```

ajax.js

```
jQuery(".myaction-button").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var post_id = jQuery(this).data('id');
    var limit = 2;
  // offset is the amount of posts which are loaded already
  var offset = 2;
    jQuery.ajax({
        url : postmyaction.ajax_url,
        type : 'post',
        data : {
            action : 'post_myaction_add_myaction',
            post_id : post_id,
            limit: limit,
            offset: offset

        },
        success : function( data ) {
            offset = offset + limit;
            jQuery('#myaction-count').append(data);

        }
    });

    return false;
})
```

I want to show images in click 2, after click other 2,,,sequentially.

This work but repeat the same value
I have 31 images, but the request just repeat the first and second image, not continue with 3,4  5,6..etc.

I want to be better, if you find something wrong with my code, please tell me how to improve. Thank you very much.

**Update:**

something strange is happening. I created another post and I attach new images and when I click on the button ajax, I get well the first 4 clicks (2+ 2 + 2 + 2) in the fifth click imagnes begins to repeat, I have reviewed the code and can not find the problem, See the capture of problem: dropbox.com/s/g732sxyn7w4ep1r/example-ajax-data-repeat.jpg?dl=0

¿How can I fixed this problem?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I think, there is a problem with ur 'offset', try to set the offset with $(selector_img).length. In my oppinion, offset is awlasy equals to 2.

Comment: Why are you returning all images? ` 'numberposts'    => -1,` is in itself a bad thing to do - if you have 1000000 of them you are querying all of them (and you usually never need all of them at once). Limit them to 2, then with ajax load 2 on click every time.

Comment: Can you please give a example, Thanks for your comment I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you have several issues. This should fix it:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_post_myaction_add_myaction', 'post_myaction_add_myaction' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_post_myaction_add_myaction', 'post_myaction_add_myaction' );

function post_myaction_add_myaction($size = 'full') {

    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    $limit = $_POST['limit'];
    $offset = $_POST['offset'];

        // get images using the get_posts() function
        $images = get_posts(array(
            'numberposts'    => $limit,
            'post_parent'    => $post_id, // get images attached to the current post
            'offset'         => $offset,
            'post_mime_type' => 'image', // so we can get images
            'post_type'      => 'attachment',
            'order'          => 'ASC',
            'orderby'        => 'menu_order' // pull them out in the order you set them as
        ));

        // loop through images and display them
        $out = '';
        foreach($images as $image) {
            setup_postdata( $image );
            $out .= wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID, $size); // returns an image HTML tag if there is one
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();

        wp_die($out);

}
```

Here you had `numberposts` set to `-1` and `$limit`. You need to remove the `-1` because you don't need to return all the images, only 2 at the time. Also you echoed the results. Don't echo, return.

Define an empty variable, then fill it in your loop. Also do a [`setup_postdata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) when using [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts). And always reset your postdata once you've done with query.

Next you need to use either `die()` or `wp_die()` with the variable to output since this is what actually outputs the response in AJAX call.

For your jQuery, assuming you're inside the script where you've localized your `admin-ajax.php` url

```
var post_id = $(this).data('id');
var limit = 2;
var offset = 0; // offset is the amount of posts which are loaded already

$('.myaction-button').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: postmyaction.ajax_url, // in Twenty sixteen it's screenReaderText.ajax_url
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            action: 'post_myaction_add_myaction',
            post_id: post_id,
            limit: limit,
            offset: offset
        },
        success: function( data ) {
            var $data = $(data);
            $('#myaction-count').append($data);
        },
        complete: function() {
            offset += limit;
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

First get the data you have in your divs, set the limit and offset, and then on click execute the ajax call, and when you're complete increase the offset by limit (number of posts) - this will correctly increase the offset by 2 every time your AJAX call is completed.

Tested this on Tewnty sixteen and it worked :) Hope this helps ^^

Comment: First,  Dingo thank you for your presence here, thank you very much for participating. I test you modification code and this work, but I have the last problem of update:  I get well the first 4 clicks (2+ 2 + 2 + 2) in the fifth click the images begins to repeat, I have reviewed the code and can not find the problem, See the capture of problem: dropbox.com/s/g732sxyn7w4ep1r/example-ajax-data-repeat.jpg?dl=0     my question ¿ is have you test with several images like 14 or 16 images ? Thanks for your support.

Comment: Tested it and none of them are repeating. In the Chrome inspector you can see in Network tab, when you select XHR all the `admin-ajax.php` requests and there you can see the offset and limit. In my case I don't have post parent, maybe this is wrong with your end...

Comment: I am happy  finally able to find the cause of problem, I removed from $images = get_posts(array(   'orderby'        => 'menu_order' with this I find the cause problem, I do not know why this happens, but thanks for your code and you test, with this I can find the solution.  Last question, you think I convert the code php to use wp_query relation to get_posts. Thanks for all your help, have a good day.

Comment: Sure, `get_posts()` uses `WP_Query()` for fetching the posts, you can use which ever you think suits you better. `WP_Query()` is the general class that queries the database for posts, pages, attachments (anything in the `wp_posts` table).

Answer (score 1):

Every time you get in the click action you reset your "offset" value to 2.

You need to make it a global variable outside of this handler.
You can also put it in a hidden element if you prefer.

As suggested, here is a simple snippet of code :

```
var offset = 2; // global
jQuery(".myaction-button").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var post_id = jQuery(this).data('id');

  // offset is the amount of posts which are loaded already
  var limit = 2;
    jQuery.ajax({
        url : postmyaction.ajax_url,
        type : 'post',
        data : {
            action : 'post_myaction_add_myaction',
            post_id : post_id,
            limit: limit,
            offset: offset

        },
        success : function( data ) {
            offset = offset + limit;
            jQuery('#myaction-count').append(data);

        }
    });

    return false;
})
```

Comment: That was easy, Thanks.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, something strange is happening.
I created another post and I attach new images and when I click on the button ajax, I get well the first 4 clicks (2+ 2 + 2 + 2)
in the fifth click imagnes begins to repeat,  I have reviewed the code and can not find the problem,

See the capture of problem:                                              

https://www.dropbox.com/s/g732sxyn7w4ep1r/example-ajax-data-repeat.jpg?dl=0                                                                                 

Thank you very much.

Comment: How many images in total do you have in your database? Can you show the html also or put it in a jsfiddle? I don't think it's related to your ajax function, but could be something else in the code.

Comment: Is a plugin in wordpress  Note: In that post I have 30 images.